# How to write dictionary with key-value pair (both having integer values) into excel through python pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Dictionary contains both integer values of key-value pair. If it is passed via python pandas, it results in

> "ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index".
>    How to overcome this problem and to write both key and value in 2 separate columns using python pandas

```
Dic={1:1,2:2,3:3}
```

In Excel, Column A contains the dictionary key and Column B contains the dictionary values

Comment: "passed via python pandas" to where? can you elaborate the question a little? thanks

Comment: are you using something like this ? `df = pd.DataFrame(list(dict.items()), columns=['key', 'value'])` or `pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(dict,orient='index'))`

Answer (score -1):

As your question is not clear to me try this if you want to create the dictionary from a dataframe:

```
dict(zip(df.col1, df.col2))
```

I am assuming that the col1 and col2 are from the excel and you converted it to a data frame called df

And try this if you want to convert this dictionary to pandas dataframe:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(Dic.items(), columns=['A', 'B'])
```

to convert it into excel:

```
df.to_csv(df.csv,index=False)
```